# MPI:Overload vs Underload, and its costs for communication

Tags: mpi, openmpi, hpc

From my code and tracing tools (Scalasca), I get various costs from same code when overload and underload is changed.

This is my result:
[image: Scalasca result]

I have search on Google, but I can not find any explanations about overload and underload, and its effects to communication cost.

So can any one explain for me? Can we have any ways to fix it to a constant value?

I have done on same cluster.
This is my code:

```c
void MST_BCast(void* data,int root,int left,int right,MPI_Datatype datatype,MPI_Comm communicator,int count)
{
    if(left==right) return;
  int me; 
  MPI_Comm_rank(communicator, &me); 
  int world_size; 
  MPI_Comm_size(communicator, &world_size);
  int mid=(int)floor(((float)(left+right)/2));
  int dest;
  if(root<=mid)
      dest=right;
  else
      dest=left;
  printf("left=%d-right=%d,me=%d,mid=%d,dest=%d\n",left,right,me,mid,dest);
  if(me==root)
      MPI_Send(data, count, datatype, dest, 0, communicator);
  if(me==dest)
  {
      MPI_Recv(data, count, datatype, root, 0, communicator, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
  if((me<=mid)&&(root<=mid))
      MST_BCast(data,root,left,mid,datatype,communicator,count);
  else if((me<=mid)&&(root>mid))
      MST_BCast(data,dest,left,mid,datatype,communicator,count);
  else if((me>mid)&&(root<=mid))
      MST_BCast(data,dest,mid+1,right,datatype,communicator,count);
  else if((me>mid)&&(root>mid))
      MST_BCast(data,root,mid+1,right,datatype,communicator,count);
  ;
}
void test(void* buff,int world_size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MST_BCast(buff,0,0,world_size-1, MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD,400); 
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); 
    int world_rank,world_size,namelen; 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    int* buff=(int*) malloc(world_size*sizeof(int)*100);
    int i;
      for (i = 0; i < world_size*100; i++) {
          if(world_rank==0)
              buff[i]=10;
          else
          buff[i]=world_rank;
      }
    test(buff,world_size);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: The two metrics and many more are explained in [those VI-HPS tutorial slides](http://www.training.prace-ri.eu/uploads/tx_pracetmo/Scalasca_Patterns.pdf).

Comment: @HristoIliev I understand its definitions,but why my programs get various overload and underload with same cluster and same code ??

Comment: From diagnosic, i see that overload will be higher if some processes perform computations which other processes don`t perform it.But i don`t think that my code has some computation for only some processes ( it is only Broadcast for all processes ) . However,sometimes my master process has high overload , but i think by some other reasons ??
Can tell me more about overload reasons ???

Comment: I have checked with only MPI_Init. Each running , i get various cost time even with MPI_Init ( no communication )